# Mage_Catalog_Model_Product is missing attributes

Tags: catalog, performance

in `frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml` round line 48 the `$_product` is fetched from the collection.

Our products have a `style` attribute. But that is missing here.

```
var_dump(get_class($_product)); // Mage_Catalog_Model_Product 
var_dump( $_product->getAttributeText('style') // false
```

If below that I do this:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load( $_product->getId() );
var_dump(get_class($_product)); // Mage_Catalog_Model_Product 
var_dump( $_product->getAttributeText('style') // get the string with the value
```

But (re)loading every product here for 1 attrubute is probably bad for performance.
What is going on here? How can I do this better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For performance reasons, not all attributes are loaded in the collection.
Only the ones marked with "Used in product listing" (and a few other system attributes).
You should edit the attribute in the backend (`Catalog->Attributes->Manage attributes`) and set the flag `Used in product listing` to `Yes`.
A flat catalog reindex is required after that.

*Side note*: be careful with how many attributes you set to be used in product listing. If they are too many, you might end up going over the sql max row limit.

Comment: Thnx that helps.